# How to refer to myself in a research paper?

Tags: writing-style, writing, research, third-person

Okay so I have collected personal spending data of myself and significant other over a period of 6 months. I'm quite happy with the data and would like to present it and write it up as a research paper. I'm not going to be publishing it but would like to do it for fun (and a bit of practice can't hurt).

The dilemma I am facing at the moment is that I cannot figure out how to refer to myself or my significant other as participants in the study. I have been trying to figure this out for a few days now and google is really giving me a hard time. I cannot find a single thing relevant to what I am trying to do.

My first issue I have come to is that I am captioning a figure that reads similar to this. Figure 1: Average daily spending vs time for **myself** (solid line) and **significant other** (dotted line).

Is this the correct way to refer to myself and significant other? It feels much too informal for my liking. I have considered making a small statement that states that myself will be referred to as "participant A" and my significant other will be referred to as "participant B", but this might add unnecessary confusion.

Is there a standard on this? This has been driving me absolutely crazy over the past few days and would really appreciate any insight or suggestions.

Comment: Your issue is rather specific but in general in a scientific paper you would refer to yourself as _the author_ or _the researcher_. You can use both e.g. when you did empirical research of some sort or when you want to describe your scientific approach or method.

Comment: These kind of questions should be asked at [academia.se] or [writers.se]. :)

Comment: Thank you for your response, I really appreciate it. I don't think this is entirely helpful though because you haven't suggested a way to refer to my significant other (the other participant). Should I refer to her as just "participant" and myself the way you suggested?

Comment: That's why I didn't answer but just commented. I feel like you can actually use significant other as I consider it formal enough. I am not an English native, though!

Comment: Oh I see, I appreciate your input anyways :). Thank you dannii, I have taken your advice, I am very keen on finding an answer to this!

Comment: The real question is: which discipline does your research belong in? Different disciplines have different conventions. Look up a paper on a similar topic and see what they do.

Comment: Isn't your sample size a little small?

Comment: "significant other" sounds like the person is your life-partner or spouse. Why not *colleague* or *collaborator*?

Comment: Unless,,, the research is about yourself and your long-term partner with whom you have a romantic relationship. You could use the term *partner* or *companion* both of which sounds less detached and impersonal. EDIT: Oh, now I get it. It's an informal report no one is going to read it other than yourself and your partner, you can call the parties involved Participant A and Participant B, or substitute the initials with your last names,..there is no right or wrong way in a paper that will never be published.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is more appropriate at Academia or Writers.

Comment: @curiousdannii Doesn't that warrant close-voting?

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I probably did - in April.

Comment: @curiousdannii The way this site operates sometimes baffles me. Thanks for supplying the close-vote reason; I wasn't aware of Academia.

Answer (score 3):

You'd normally follow your organisation's style guide. Here's an excerpt from one I found on the internet:

> It is a common misconception that foregrounding the research requires using the passive voice ("Experiments have been conducted ..."). This is inaccurate. Rather, you would use pronouns in place of "experiments" ("We conducted experiments ...").
>   [- APA Formatting and Style Guide, Purdue Online Writing Lab](https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/560/15/)

Hee's another, again based on APA:

> It is totally acceptable to write in the first person in an APA Style paper. If you did something, say, “I did it”—there’s no reason to hide your own agency by saying “the author [meaning you] did X” or to convolute things by using the passive “X was done [meaning done by you].”  If you’re writing a paper alone, use I as your pronoun. If you have coauthors, use we.
>   However, avoid using we to refer to broader sets of people—researchers, students, psychologists, Americans, people in general, or even all of humanity—without specifying who you mean (a practice called using the editorial “we”). This can introduce ambiguity into your writing.
>   [- Chelsea Lee](http://blog.apastyle.org/apastyle/2014/05/me-me-me.html)

The above describe how you would refer to yourself as the *researcher*.

Now, researchers don't normally conduct research on themselves. What you describe is a case study with yourself and your significant other as the participants. What you call yourselves *as participants* depends on how you view the case study.

If you consider this to be a personal journal, using personal pronouns would be entirely appropriate. If you consider this to be "a bit of practice" for a research paper, it would be appropriate to treat the role of participant as a third-party role and pretend (for the sake of practice) that others filled that role. In that case, you can choose to give yourselves labels or aliases, or even refer to yourselves in the third person.

You ask:

> Is there a standard on this?

As the excerpts above indicate, there are good grounds for using personal pronouns where they are relevant and where the context clearly identifies the people to whom the pronouns refer. Nevertheless, in practice, the *standard on this* remains your organisation's style guide.

Comment: This is APA. Other disciplines have different rules. See [this academia.SE question](http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/15344/what-to-use-instead-of-academic-we-when-describing-an-experiment#comment161962_16087).

Comment: @PeterShor Yes, that's why I referred the OP to his/her "organisation's style guide" - see the start *and* the end of my answer. I prefer the appropriate use of personal pronouns to the more cumbersome *this author* or *the present writer*, but (I'll repeat once more :) ) the OP should follow his/her **organisation's style guide** when writing a real research report.

Comment: Would you really use the expression "significant other" in a research paper? Doesn't it sound like a companion, spouse or long-term girl/boyfriend?

Comment: @Mari-LouA It's the OP's term. If the write-up is treated as a case study, then participants have some leeway *subject to the organisation's style guide* to choose how they should be identified. Likewise, the researcher can use terminology to include or exclude various considerations such as marriage status. With the organisation's style guide, the research discipline (finance vs psychology vs sociology, etc) and the focus of the research all unknown (other than *a couple's personal spending*), I don't think we are in a position to say that any term is better or worse than *significant other*.

Answer (score 1):

There are **two different conditions to satisfy** by compiling and presenting your research project. Differentiating between the two will greatly simplify your "dilemma."

**Content**: The first is to present your research data and findings in a clear, well-written form for *understanding*. There are simply two subjects involved in the project and differentiating between the two is the issue. You may use any terms that suit you. Participant #, Subject, First name, contributor, person, party, etc.

**Credit**: The second issue is to identify yourself as the author. This is done in a conventional manner according to any reference you prefer. If your significant other has contributed content, *co-author* can be used along with their name and credentials.

If no contribution was made other than as a data source, no authorship credit mention is due your partner. However, there is nothing to prevent you from a short write-up as an introduction in the Abstract, or a post-script comment, thanking your significant other for their participation.